# bootstrap - move text from one div into other on screen size change

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

I am trying to create a login screen with 2 columns.

**On large screens**: Left column = login controls, right column = Image.

**on small screens**: Top column = image, bottom column = login controls.

It works as expected. like the screenshots below:

[image]

[image]

So far, it works well. However, I want the "Sign in" and the "Welcome" text to appear inside the image on the smaller screens.

To get an Idea on what I am trying to achieve, please look at this Website login page. They have done it:

https://demo.hasthemes.com/adomx-preview/light/login.html

Here is my code so far.

```
<div class="container-fluid fullheight">

<div class="row fullheight">

  <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-6 col-lg-8 order-md-2 order-lg-2" style="background-color: grey;">
    this is my image panel
  </div>

  <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-6 col-lg-4 order-md-1 order-lg-1">

    <div class="loginarea">
      <h2>Sign in</h2>
      <p class="text-muted">Welcome to MySite. Please sign in with your email id and password to access your
        profile, reports and orders.</p>

      <form style="margin-top: 30px; margin-bottom: 20px;">
        <div class="form-group">
          <input type="email" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter email">
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
          <input type="password" class="form-control" placeholder="Password">
        </div>
        <div class="form-check">
          <input type="checkbox" class="form-check-input" id="exampleCheck1">
          <label class="form-check-label" for="exampleCheck1">Remember Me</label>
        </div>
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary float-right">Sign in</button>
      </form>

      <a href="#">Forgot password</a>
    </div>

  </div>

</div>
```

and this is my simple CSS.

```
   <style>
    .fullheight {
      height: 100%;
      min-height: 100%;
    }

    html,
    body {
      height: 100%;
    }

    .loginarea {
      margin-top: 100px;
      padding-right: 20px;
      padding-left: 20px;
    }
  </style>
```

How can I make the Text lines flow into the image and the white area contain only the login boxes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using latest version of bootstrap i.e version 4 then you should use the d-* class as follows.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
<title>Document</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<div class="container-fluid fullheight">

<div class="row fullheight">

<div class="col-sm-12 col-md-6 col-lg-8 order-md-2 order-lg-2" style="background-color: grey;">
this is my image panel
<div class="loginarea d-sm-none">
<h2>Sign in</h2>
<p class="text-muted">Welcome to MySite. Please     sign in with your email id and password to access your
profile, reports and orders.</p>
</div>
</div>

<div class="col-sm-12 col-md-6 col-lg-4 order-md-1 order-lg-1">

<div class="loginarea">
<div class="d-none d-sm-block">
<h2>Sign in</h2>
<p class="text-muted">Welcome to MySite. Please sign in with your email id and password to access your
profile, reports and orders.</p>
</div>


<form style="margin-top: 30px; margin-bottom: 20px;">
<div class="form-group">
<input type="email" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter email">
</div>

<div class="form-group">
<input type="password" class="form-control" placeholder="Password">
</div>
<div class="form-check">
<input type="checkbox" class="form-check-input" id="exampleCheck1">
<label class="form-check-label" for="exampleCheck1">Remember Me</label>
</div>
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary float-right">Sign in</button>
</form>

<a href="#">Forgot password</a>
</div>

</div>
</body>
</html>
```

this is as you expected